# I want to make an alias to edit a file using nano. Is it possible?

Tags: shell, files

I basically want to make an alias to modify '***/etc/systemd/logind.conf***' file. To change

```
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

To

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't even need nano. You could do it like this:

```
alias enableLid='sudo sed -i "s/^#HandleLidSwitch=ignore/HandleLidSwitch=ignore/" /etc/systemd/logind.conf'

alias disableLid='sudo sed -i "s/^HandleLidSwitch=ignore/#HandleLidSwitch=ignore/" /etc/systemd/logind.conf'
```

If you want to have one alias to toggle the setting I would create a shell script for it. If you want to use nano anyway:

```
alias editLogindconf='sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf'
```